# hex byte array from image is padded with spaces and - after INSERT to table postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a problem while inserting images into byte array data structures in postgreSQL database.

In particular after I perform the INSERT instruction, I query the image from the db but what I get is not the original content of the image but a sequence of space and "-" before the "\x....".

What should I get instead is just the "\x" followed by the hex byte array which corresponds to the image that I inserted.

I tried both inserting directly the raw hex byte array from the psql database and from jdbc and i get the same result.

For instance, the sql instruction is the following:

```
INSERT INTO profile VALUES ("label", "\x..........");
```

After the \x obviously there is the hex content of the image.

The java code is long but if needed i can provide also it.

Which can be the problem?

An example of output from the query of the image:

```
                                                                                                     image         


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000000b0000000b080200000026cee071000000097048597300000ec400000ec401952b0e1b0000
008b4944415418574d90415644310804abc8dcff3e9ecb9dcf49b948fc1a164077d30fe2e7c717c0e0b2778e7de7d80e005e27b1a91c7be7faa
3cfec6f1904d03bc0f15043b804904a455c9706e642738176746daea2633d383ece74a5c0eb24ba715b6ee1f26f53957f0b3eef253ea78a914b
3691d86eaa768e4abbe3748eca5cbe1c8f2878feea806c58fc0003f05bd3a47a34520000000049454e44ae426082
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the data was not padded and was printed correctly, the "-" characters were simply added when I was trying the query in psql.

In fact when you execute a query from command line you get something like:

```
label
-----
value
```

Since my data is very long it adds all the - like if it would have been printed in only one line